# How can I tell a CPAN installation of PDL to use my FFTW path?

Tags: perl, linker, shared-libraries, cpan, fftw

I need to install the Perl [PDL library](http://pdl.perl.org) via CPAN as the non-root user.

CPAN for non-root works thanks to this SO question: [How can I use CPAN as a non-root user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980297/how-can-i-use-cpan-as-a-non-root-user)

Now, PDL depends on the FFTW library. Evidently, my sysadmin has the 32-bit version installed when I require the 64-bit for this machine.

I base this on the following error message during the CPAN install:

```
gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic FFTW.o  -o ../../blib/arch/auto/PDL/FFTW/FFTW.so   \
       -lm -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -ldfftw -ldrfftw     \

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libdfftw.a when searching for -ldfftw
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libdfftw.a when searching for -ldfftw
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldfftw
```

Now I have successfully installed fftw in `$HOME/lib`, indeed `libdfftw.a`.

The problem is I can't get this gcc compilation instance to use that locally installed copy.

I have tried the following:

1. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bash_profile, and yes, exporting it  -- No dice.
2. Following [How can I set library and include paths for Makefile.PL for a single installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826449/how-can-i-set-library-and-include-paths-for-makefile-pl-for-a-single-installatio), I set `o conf makepl_arg` in `cpan` to: `LIBS=-L/homedir/lib INC=-I/homedir/include`   -- Still no dice
3. I did the same as step 2 but for `o conf mbuild_arg` --- Again, no dice.

None of these attempts had any effect on the `gcc` line above; there were no additional paths specified with `-L` flags.

What else can I try in `cpan` to get this compilation command to reference my copy of fftw?

**Update 1**

I should add that before I make any changes, `makepl_arg` is:

`makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]`

Hence, I am setting `makepl_arg` to:

`makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site LIBS=-L/homedir/lib INC=-I/homedir/include]`

I am setting these configurations without doing `o conf commit` to permit experimentation. Should I be commiting these changes?

**Update 2**

I see that those `-L` flags in the above `gcc` line are coming from the makefile, which itself seems to be made by MakeMaker which I presume is reading the file 'Makefile.PL'

Comment: Double check what you did in step 2, please. Do you see `LIBS=-L/homedir/lib INC=-I/homedir/include` when you do `o conf makepl_arg`?

Comment: (Step 3 uses an incorrect value for `mbuild_arg`, but PDL uses `makepl_arg`, so not an issue.)

Comment: I just tried it again ikegami, but unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: Note: PDL does not depend on the FFTW library, its optional. If you need FFTW support obviously you need it. Otherwise there are a few other FFT components of PDL.

Comment: Ok, that's good. AS for `o conf commit`, it's not necessary if you don't exit before doing `install PDL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to examine the `.cpan/build/PDL-*/` directory.

In it the INSTALL file indicates that the `perldl.conf` file can be modified to indicate paths to FFTW libs and FFTW include directories.

The process is as follows and can be done after a failed attempt at installing PDL:

1. Copy the `.cpan/build/PDL-*/perldl.conf` file to `~/.perldl.conf` - notice the `.` being added before the filename - PDL will look for this file when installing, even under CPAN
2. Modify `FFTW__LIBS` and `FFTW_INC` in `~/.perldl.conf` to point to the appropriate locations.
3. Attempt install of PDL again with CPAN.

A bit confusing that PDL does not adhere to the `makepl_arg` cpan configuration.